# How to get number of rows equal to zero instead of nothing if table is empty is SAS

Tags: sas

I have the following code, which stores the number of rows in a table inside the macro-variable `n_vars`:

```
data cont_vars;
   set var_list;
   where flg_categorical = 0;
   call symput('n_vars', _n_);
   %put &n_vars;
run;
```

Currently if the resulting table is empty then `n_vars` resolves to nothing and I want it to be set equal to 0 so I can use it in a `%do x = 1 %to &n_vars;` loop later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `where` statement indeed leads to no observation in the dataset, the following code should then set the `n_vars` macro-variable to `0`:

```
data want;
  if eof then call symputx('n_vars',_n_-1);
  set have end=eof;
  where flg_categorical = 0;
run;
```

Please consider creating a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUxLi.png).

```
data have;
infile datalines delimiter=',';
input x1 flg_categorical;
datalines;                      
1,1
6,2
3,2
;
run;

data want;
  if eof then call symputx('n_vars',_n_-1);
  set have end=eof;
  where flg_categorical = 0;
run;
%put &=n_vars;
```

Result:

[image]

Anyway I don't know see why you would use a `%do` loop that would be incremented from `1 to 0`.
Maybe you just want to run another kind of steps when the data set is empty. If that is the case, I would consider using:

```
%if &n_vars. > 0 %then %do; /* data set is not empty */
...
%end;
%else %do; /* data set is empty */
...
%end;
```